# Parametrized tests using Nunit 3.x

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am having following scenario while testing and I want to ask you guys if there is shortcut for testing this.

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(MlTestCases))]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(QaTestCases))]
public void EditBetSlip_ShouldConvertOddsFromAmericanToDecimal(string selectionId)
{
    // Arrange
    var betSlipRequest = new PostBetSlipRequest
    {
        OddStyle = OddStyle.American.ToString(),
        Selections = new List<PostOneSelectionRequest>
        {
            new PostOneSelectionRequest
            {
                DisplayOdds = $"+{Fixture.Create<int>()}",
                Id = selectionId.Replace("#", "%23"),
            },
        },
        Bets = new List<PostOneBetRequest>
        {
            new PostOneBetRequest
            {
                OddStyle = OddStyle.American.ToString(),
                Id = 0,
                Stake = 10,
            },
        },
    };

    // Act
    _client.EditBetslip(betSlipRequest);
    var response = _client.RefreshBetslip(new GetBetSlipRequest { OddStyle = OddStyle.European.ToString() });
    var betslip = response.DeserializedBody;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);

    foreach (var selection in betslip.Selections)
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => decimal.Parse(selection.DisplayOdds));
    }
}
```

Now I need to make the same test again but simply flip the `OddStyle` of `PostBetSlipRequest` and `GetBetSlipRequest`. I tried with `[Values]` attribute but it doesn't work the way I want.

What I want is to execute all these two test case sources once with `American - European` and another time with `European - American` is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Surely each scenario (US --> Eur & Eur --> US) is a new test case for the test method?

As is you have n test cases where n = the total number of QaTestCases + the total number of MlTestCases.

You actually want to test 2n test cases (each existing test case for each [Eur --> US, US --> Eur] permuatation). Id suggest that this therefore should just be a new `TestCaseSource` using the existing ones and adding in the Eur/US permutations.

Stripping it right back, you have something vaguely like this just now:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCaseSourceA))]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCaseSourceB))]
public void GivenX_ShouldReturnOk(string input)
{
    //some test
    Assert.Pass();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> TestCaseSourceA()
{
    yield return "a1";
    yield return "a2";
}
public static IEnumerable<string> TestCaseSourceB()
{
    yield return "b1";
    yield return "b2";
}
```

giving this set of results: [image: test output]

Whereas you really want something more like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCaseSourceMaster))]
public void GivenX_ShouldReturnOk(string input, string fromOddsStyle, string toOddsStyle)
{
    //some test
    Assert.Pass();
}

public static IEnumerable<string[]> TestCaseSourceMaster()
{
    return TestCaseSourceA()
        .Concat(TestCaseSourceB())
        .SelectMany(t => new string[][]
        {
            new string[]{t,"US","Eur"},
            new string[]{t,"Eur","Us"}
        });
}

public static IEnumerable<string> TestCaseSourceA()
{
    yield return "a1";
    yield return "a2";
}
public static IEnumerable<string> TestCaseSourceB()
{
    yield return "b1";
    yield return "b2";
}
```

[image: test screensnip new]

Comment: Hmm yea, I was actually kinda doing that later after I posted the question, but now I find it a bit cumbersome because I need to write all those static "helper" methods that will pollute my test fixture(sure I can extract them in another class, but still)